# SystemC - Can I retrieve clock period from sc_in_clk port?

Tags: systemc

Can I retrieve the clock period through `sc_port`?

The following code doesn't work. I'd like to call method `period()` defined in `sc_clock`.

```
sc_in_clk clk;

*clk.get_interface()->period();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dynamic_cast<>` to cast the `sc_interface` returned by `get_interface()` as an `sc_clock`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <systemc>

using namespace std;
using namespace sc_core;

SC_MODULE(A) {
    sc_in_clk clk;

    SC_CTOR(A) {}

    void start_of_simulation() {
        sc_clock *channel = dynamic_cast<sc_clock *>(clk.get_interface());
        cout << name() << ": period is "
             << (channel ? channel->period() : SC_ZERO_TIME) << endl;
    }
};

int sc_main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A a1("a1");
    A a2("a2");

    sc_clock clk("clk", 3.0, SC_NS);
    sc_signal<bool> fake_clk("fake_clk");

    a1.clk(clk);
    a2.clk(fake_clk);

    sc_start(10, SC_NS);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This works because `sc_clock` is a subclass of `sc_interface`.

If `dynamic_cast<>` succeeds, then a valid `sc_clock` pointer is returned. If it fails, `NULL` is returned.